# Remove others in a string except a needed word including certain patterns in R

Tags: r

I have a vector including certain strings, and I would like remove other parts in each string except the word including certain patter (here is `mir`).

```r
s <- c("a mir-96 line (kk27)", "mir-133a cell", 
       "d mir-14-3p in", "m mir133 (sas)", "mir_23_5p r 27")
```

I want to obtain:

`mir-96`, `mir-133a`, `mir-14-3p`, `mir133`, `mir_23_5p`

I know the idea: use the `gsub()` and pattern is: *a word beginning with (or including) **mir***.

But I have no idea how to construct such patter.

Or other idea?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by a word boundary (`\\b`) followed by the string (`mir` and one or more characters that are not a white space (`\\S+`), capture it as a group by placing inside the `(...)` followed by other characters, and in the replacement use the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
sub(".*\\b(mir\\S+).*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "mir-96"    "mir-133a"  "mir-14-3p" "mir133"    "mir_23_5p"
```

#### Update

If there are multiple 'mir.*' substring, then we want to extract strings having some numeric part

```
sub(".*\\b(mir[^0-9]*[0-9]+\\S*).*", "\\1", s1)
#[1] "mir-96"    "mir-133a"  "mir-14-3p" "mir133"    "mir_23_5p" "mir_23-5p"
```

#### data

```
s1 <- c("a mir-96 line (kk27)", "mir-133a cell", "d mir-14-3p in", "m mir133 (sas)", 
                                            "mir_23_5p r 27", "a mir_23-5p 1 mir-net")
```

Comment: if `s <- "a mir_23-5p 1 mir-net"`, then `sub(".*\\b(mir\\S+).*", "\\1", s)` return `"mir-net"`, but I want to `"mir_23-5p"`. What is the better way to deal with such condition?

Answer (score 2):

One way in base R would be splitting every string into words and then extracting only those with `mir` in it

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, " "), function(x) grep("mir", x, value = TRUE)))
#[1] "mir-96"    "mir-133a"  "mir-14-3p" "mir133"    "mir_23_5p"
```

We can save the `unlist` step in `lapply` by using `sapply` as suggested by @Rich Scriven in comments

```
sapply(strsplit(s, " "), function(x) grep("mir", x, value = TRUE))
```